# How to properly save IFS in KornShell (ksh)

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, aix, ifs

I'm trying to save my IFS before modifying it in a KornShell (ksh) script. I found that the back up variable was not getting saved properly, so I wrote a simple script to reproduce the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

OFIS=$IFS
echo "$IFS" | od -b
echo "$OIFS" | od -b
```

What I expect to see when I echo OIFS is the same thing as when I echo IFS, which is the octal ascii values for a space (040), a tab(011) and a newline(012). However, this is the output:

```
0000000  040 011 012 012
0000004
0000000  012
0000001
```

Notice that the output of the IFS variable contains all three characters, while the output of OIFS just contains a newline (012).  Every forum I have looked at has indicated that this is the way to create a copy of an IFS.  Does anyone know why OIFS is not getting set properly?  I also tried enclosing $IFS in double quotes like so, but got the same results:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

OFIS="$IFS"
echo "$IFS" | od -b
echo "$OIFS" | od -b
```

```
0000000  040 011 012 012
0000004
0000000  012
0000001
```

I'm running on AIX6.

Comment: You're going to kick yourself: `OFIS` != `OIFS`

Comment: I wish I was flexible enough to kick myself in the head, but I suppose banging it against a wall will have to suffice.  Thanks :)

Comment: +1 for easily digested test-case. Too bad about the typo ;-) Good luck to all.

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are not strictly required for *assignment*:

```
foo="  lots   of    spaces   "
bar=$foo
echo ">$bar<"
```

```
>  lots   of    spaces   <
```

Of course, quotes are usually required when you *use* a variable.